# Normalize within groups in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a set of data that has a grouping variable, a position, and a value at that position:

```
Sample    Position    Depth
A         1           2
A         2           3
A         3           4
B         1           1
B         2           3
B         3           2
```

I want to generate a new column that is an internally normalized depth as follows:

```
Sample    Position    Depth    NormalizedDepth
A         1           2        0
A         2           3        0.5
A         3           4        1
B         1           1        0
B         2           3        1
B         3           2        0.5
```

This is essentially represented by the formula `NormalizedDepth = (x - min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))` such that the minimum and maximum are of the group.

I know how to do this with `dplyr` in `R` with the following:

```r
depths %>% 
  group_by(Sample) %>%
  mutate(NormalizedDepth = 100 * (Depth - min(Depth))/(max(Depth) - min(Depth)))
```

I cannot figure out how to do this with `pandas`. I've tried doing grouping and applying, but none of it seems to replicate what I am looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have `transform` (do the same as `mutate` in R `dplyr` ) with `ptp` (thes is get the diff between the max and min )

```
import numpy as np

g = df.groupby('Sample').Depth
(df.Depth-g.transform('min')) / g.transform(np.ptp)
```

```
0    0.0
1    0.5
2    1.0
3    0.0
4    1.0
5    0.5
Name: Depth, dtype: float64
```

Comment: In using python-3.5.6 and this code, I see `FutureWarning: Method .ptp is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use numpy.ptp instead.` Is there an alternate way of using `np.ptp`?

Comment: @r2evans you can do transform(lambda x : x.max()-x.min()), and numpy ptp still work for me :-)

Comment: @r2evans I think you were accidentally using `pd.Series.ptp`. It was removed in Pandas 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

Group the Data Frame by Sample Series' values, apply an anonymous function to each value of the (split) Depth Series which performs min max normalisation, assign result to NormalizedDepth Series of df DataFrame (note unlikely to be as efficient as YOBEN_S' answer above):

```
import pandas as pd    
df['NormalizedDepth'] = df.groupby('Sample').Depth.apply(lambda x: (x - min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)))
```